# "Show Less" link not working?

Tags: jquery, html

"Show Less" link isn't working, but "Show More" is, and I don't know what is wrong with my jQuery code. Can someone help me with this?

HTML

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In sunt aut deleniti nihil quidem, maxime rem numquam ea quibusdam ut commodi hic fuga dolorum. Ab reprehenderit dolorem nemo error illo. Animi magni modi laudantium nisi eum cum sit minus. Repellat, esse nobis itaque ratione officia suscipit quo, saepe ipsam ab consequatur iusto commodi, quis praesentium aut consectetur sapiente officiis nesciunt quisquam velit magnam sequi nulla optio. Rem accusamus eum nam nobis officia? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem accusamus eum nam nobis officia?<a class="toggleButton"> Show More </a>
    <p class="show-text" display="none">Animi magni modi laudantium nisi eum cum sit minus. Repellat, esse nobis itaque ratione officia suscipit quo, saepe ipsam ab consequatur iusto commodi, quis praesentium aut consectetur sapiente officiis nesciunt quisquam velit magnam sequi nulla optio. Rem accusamus eum nam nobis officia?</p>
</p>
```

jQuery

```
$('.show-text').hide();

$('.toggleButton').click(function() {
    //on click, show introText
    $('.show-text').toggle();

    $('.show-text').show();
    $('.toggleButton').hide();
    $('.show-text').append("<a class = 'show-less'>" + " Show Less" + "</a>");

});

$('.show-less').click(function() {
    $('.show-less').toggle();
    $('show-text').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery code doesn't make much sense.  You can achieve this with one command `toggle()`.

```
$(".toggleButton").click(function() {
    $(".show-text").toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/os72jsf6/

Also your markup is incorrect, you need `style="display:none"` not `display="none"`

To handle the text manipulation in the function you can do something like the following, if needed.

```
$(this).text(t.text() == "Show More" ? "Show Less" : "Show More");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/os72jsf6/2/

Comment: How can I manipulate the text in this function as well so "Show More" becomes "Show Less"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `<p>` inside another `<p>`. So technically this doesn't work. There's no attribute `display` with value `none`. Instead you can do something like this:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".toggleButton").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("p").next(".show-text").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In sunt aut deleniti nihil quidem, maxime rem numquam ea quibusdam ut commodi hic fuga dolorum. Ab reprehenderit dolorem nemo error illo. Animi magni modi laudantium nisi eum cum sit minus. Repellat, esse nobis itaque ratione officia suscipit quo, saepe ipsam ab consequatur iusto commodi, quis praesentium aut consectetur sapiente officiis nesciunt quisquam velit magnam sequi nulla optio. Rem accusamus eum nam nobis officia? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem accusamus eum nam nobis officia? <a href="#" class="toggleButton"> Show More </a></p>
<p class="show-text" style="display: none">Animi magni modi laudantium nisi eum cum sit minus. Repellat, esse nobis itaque ratione officia suscipit quo, saepe ipsam ab consequatur iusto commodi, quis praesentium aut consectetur sapiente officiis nesciunt quisquam velit magnam sequi nulla optio. Rem accusamus eum nam nobis officia?</p></p>
```